# Event Contribution page missing trxn_id in template Contribution.tpl

Tags: civicontribute

Not sure when this started-the Cancellation or Refund Information block is supposed to contain cancel/refund date, a note and transaction id:  the Smarty template has the code:

              {$form.refund_trxn_id.label}
              {$form.refund_trxn_id.html}
            
but it isn't shown - this is also the case in the latest Wordpress Sandbox, if you change a contribution status to cancelled or refunded, the trxn_id box should be shown. 
I tried simply clearing templates to force recompile but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to depend on whether there was a transaction id set on the initial contribution. If there was one on the initial contribution then I see the refund trxn id on the refund. If there wasn't one on the initial contribution then I don't see a refund trxn id on the refund. This seems to be the same even in 5.5 as well as the public demo.

Comment: There's a trxn id on the initial contribution (by CC), but still I didn't get the refund trxn ID box after changing status to 'refunded' or 'cancelled' - I did find a way to make it work, though, changing 'refund_trxn_id' to 'trxn_id' (.label and .html) in the Smarty template; leaving the id as refundTrxnID. It shows the original trxnID - when I view the saved result of the refund trxn, shows the refund trxn id I input. I think it is due to 'trxn_id' being declared in the DAO while refund_trxn_id isn't, but as long as the ID is named in the template, the field is saved as the refund_trxn_id

Comment: I just tried again with credit card on wpmaster.demo and it is showing the refund trxn id when I have a trxn id on the original. It seems pretty consistent to depend on the initial contribution having a trxn id. Can you maybe edit your question with a screenshot of what you're seeing? Here's the one I just tried: https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcontact%2Fview%2Fcontribution&reset=1&id=100&cid=79&action=view&context=contribution&selectedChild=contribute

Answer (score 0):

Edit templates/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution.tpl, lines 201-204:
           
              {$form.trxn_id.label}
              {$form.trxn_id.html}
            
(replace $form.refund_trxn_id with $form.trxn_id - the existing trxnID if it exists will be shown initially and can be substituted with a refund trxn id. Save and view to verify)